# Comparación de secuencias en python

Tags: python

Muy buenas a todos!

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio que consiste en comparar los elementos que se encuentran en la misma posición en dos strings:

"Dadas dos secuencias p y q, calculad su distancia de hamming:"

p = 'CGAAGCAATTGAAACCCCCCCGGCCTGGGAGGCGCAAAAATCTGACCTCTTTGT\
GAGTTGACCACTTAATTTATGTCTGACCACGAGAAGGGCTACTGATTTGGTA'

q = 'GGTAGTAGGTTCGCGTACCTCGTTCCGGGGAAAACACAAAGGAGAAGGGAATGC\
TCCTAGTAGTTTCAGTCTAGCAAACATGTTATAACGCTAACTGTGTGCTGCA'"

Se me ha ocurrido crear la siguiente función:

```
def hamming(p, q):
    contador = 0
    for n in p,q:
        if p[]==q[]:  # Problema: como llamar a los elementos que están en la misma posición en un bucle.
            contador += 1
    return contador

print(hamming(p, q))
```

Mi pregunta es si es posible resolverlo de esta manera, se que habrá mas formas de resolverlo pero no me quiero quedar con la duda de si es posible hacerlo así!

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En cada iteracción **i**:

- **"a"** tomará el valor de la **posición i** de **"p"**
- **"b"** tomará el valor de la **posición i** de **"q"**

```
def hamming(p, q):
    contador = 0
    for (a,b) in zip(p,q):
      if a!= b:
        contador += 1
    return contador

print(hamming(p, q))
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el bucle termina cuando se ha llegado a la última posición de la lista más pequeña, es decir, si las listas son de distinto tamaño, las últimas posiciones (de la lista de mayor tamaño) no se tomarán en el bucle.

Aquí tienes más información:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-iterate-multiple-lists-simultaneously/
- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip

Comment: Hola Gonzalo! gracias por tu respuesta, el codigo que has puesto es justo lo que buscaba, tenía en mente lo que me has dicho, de hecho lo he resuelto de otra forma, pero quería saber como sería la forma correcta si lo quisiera averiguar de esta forma, me ha servido mucho tu respuesta, muchas gracias!